# Does my suggested edit plagiarize content without attribution?

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits

I've suggested an edit today, [here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5843432). It has been rejected by [the author](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4073217/vinaya-maheshwari), who has 1 rep. At the time of rejection, my edit was approved by one user, therefore it should have been visible only to me.

My questions:

- How was he able to access review queues to reject my edit?
- What's the thing about

> This edit plagiarizes content from an external source without proper attribution.

I only fixed grammar and formatting...

Comment: OP can reject any edit unilaterally I think.  The reason might just be random or a misclick.

Comment: While a riduculous reason maybe he thought for unknown reasons your edit would replace his answer and you'd get all the reps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you suggest an edit on a post, the original author gets notified, with a link to the suggested edit.

It is entirely possible that they just wanted to reject the edit and cared not about the proper reason.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that. Must be 'don't touch my stuff' case ;-)

Comment: @Mark your edit was a valid one, so I went ahead and applied it for you.  Sorry you couldn't get the +2 rep out of it, especially since you are so close to 2K